# Responsive triangles in css

Tags: html, css

I am simply trying to draw a responsive triangle in css. The height of it and the width of it should resize as the window resizes.

Here is what I have in static:

```
#triangle {
  z-index: 2;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  position:absolute;
  right:0px;
  bottom:0px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0 0 600px 1100px;
  border-color: transparent transparent #01fe77 transparent;
  line-height: 0px;
  _border-color: #000000 #000000 #01fe77 #000000;
  _filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Chroma(color='#000000');
}
```

Comment: Rather than using pixels you should use a unit which is window based. vw and vh will do the job.

Comment: Right, the question is only how responsive he needs it, to fit into some box, or just to be smaller on mobile?

Comment: Also, using svg instead of "hacky" css will be better for shapes.

Comment: @ajayGupta I have just tried and the triangle does not resize

Comment: @skobaljic it should fit in a box that is 60% of the viewport height and 80% of the view port width

Comment: @Rémi: 1vw is equal to 1% of the width of the viewport :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should look like this

```
#triangle {
  z-index: 2;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  position:absolute;
  right:0px;
  bottom:0px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0 0 60vw 60vw;
  border-color: transparent transparent #01fe77 transparent;
  line-height: 0px;
}
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Try the [viewport](https://web-design-weekly.com/2014/11/18/viewport-units-vw-vh-vmin-vmax/) width `vw` unit

```
#triangle {
  z-index: 2;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  _border-color: #000000 #000000 #01fe77 #000000;
  _filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Chroma(color='#000000');
  display: block;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0 0 50vw 100vw;
  border-color: transparent transparent #01fe77 transparent;
  line-height: 0px;
}
```

[Test it](https://jsfiddle.net/tddrk97y/1/)

Comment: @ToniMuchelCaubet Why use the "_" properties? Does it mean something?

Comment: it was in the original question, I believe it's some IE 7-8 Hacks. I think there is no need for those anymore ( http://browserhacks.com/ )